# tmux on mountain lion

Tags: macos

I have recently upgraded to mountain lion and every time I start a new tmux session, I get the following warning:

│warning: unsupported new OS, trying as if it were 10.6-10.7

Is this anything I should be worried about?

Answer (score 2):

That message comes from [my `reattach-to-user-namespace` wrapper program](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/) that let’s you (e.g.) access the pasteboard inside *tmux*. You are using an old version of the wrapper (from prior to Mountain Lion).

The old wrapper **does** work correctly under 10.8; the message just means that you are using a version from before 10.8 was available/verified. So there is nothing to worry about, but it may get annoying seeing the message every time you start a new *tmux* pane/window.

To get rid of the message, you should upgrade to a newer version of the wrapper. If you previously installed via [MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/tmux-pasteboard/Portfile) of [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/reattach-to-user-namespace.rb), just upgrade via that package manager. Otherwise, download the latest [tagged source](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/tags) (or pull into your previous Git clone), rebuild it (e.g. type `make`), and copy it to the location that your *tmux* `default-command` setting uses.

Both MacPorts and Homebrew currently package the 1.1 version, which suppresses the message when running on Mountain Lion. The 2.0 version also includes the program’s name in such messages so that the source of any future messages will be more obvious.

Comment: I just updated to Mt. Lion and reinstalled tmux and tmux-pasteboard (1.1) from macports, but I still get this message.

Comment: @kenny: What does your `default-command` look like (or however you are invoking the wrapper, if it is not through `default-command`)? Perhaps you are running some other build (e.g. an old, self-built version in your home directory instead of the one that MacPorts built and installed as `/opt/local/bin/reattach-to-user-namespace`)? The most recent package in MacPorts (`port installed tmux-pasteboard` shows `tmux-pasteboard @1.1_0 (active)`) does not issue the message on Mountain Lion (I just installed it after a fresh `port selfupdate` to verify).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I had an old self-built version in `~/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but try the new version (you can find it into the iTerm2 beta [download package](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/downloads/list))

Comment: Can you add the download link? Your post would become even more useful. Thanks!